# Chat gives me really, really specific time gap notifications

Tags: bug, chat

So, I left my computer for a little while, and came back to this:

[image]

Note all the time gap notifications for merely minutes, and seconds.

Refreshing the chat window and it all goes back to normal. Can't reproduce either I'm afraid.

Comment: **2 minutes 42 seconds later** -- That is weird.

Comment: I know I've seen that once, but don't recall the circumstances.  Maybe it's intended to drive us SF'ers crazy?